# Interaction between Windows InfluxDB and AWS InfluxDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have the following problem with the InfluxDB and Python interaction with it.

InfluxDB is installed on the Windows 7 machine, also, I have InfluxDB which is installed in the docker container in the AWS ubuntu machine. I forwarded InfluxDB port from the AWS machine to my local Windows machine.

Then, using the Python [influxdb](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library I tried to connect to both InfluxDB-s in the following way:

```
client_aws = influxdb.InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8087, '', '', 'aws_db')
client_local = influxdb.InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, '', '', 'local_db')
```

Then, I just wanted to write data from the AWS-machine to my local machine:

```
query = 'select field_name from test_aws'
rs = client_aws.query(query, params={"epoch": "us"})
points = list(rs.get_points(measurement="test_aws"))
db_body = [ { "measurement": "test_local",
              "time": query_time,
              "fields": { field_name: points[0].get("field_name") } } ]
client_local.write_points(db_body)
```

After that I checked my local InfluxDB and detected that there is no measurement "test_local" but execution of the query

```
select field_name from test_local
```

returns necessary data. Moreover, I cannot drop measurement test_local because it is not exist for local InfluxDB.

Could you help me, please? Where is my data stored? How can it be that query is executed but there is no measurement?

Answer (score 0):

A query can be executed, but return no data.

You need to make sure that the target database exists on the localhost machine before you try to insert data into it.

add a call to `client.create_database('local_db')` before your attempt to insert data into `db_local` to ensure that the database exists.